# Pressed state is not populated to my custom view

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-selector

I have a problem with my very simple custom view. Its intention is only to draw simple vertical dashed line. I would like to change the color of the line according to the pressed state of its parent container. I have this code:

```
public class DottedLine extends View {

    float density ;
    float size;
    Paint paint;

    public DottedLine(Context context) {
        this(context, null, 0);
    }

    public DottedLine(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public DottedLine(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        DisplayMetrics metrics = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        density = metrics.density;
        size = 2 * density; //2dp
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(size);
        paint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.main_kosapp));
        paint.setPathEffect(new DashPathEffect(new float[] {size, size}, 0));

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        float diff =  canvas.getHeight()%size;

        Path path = new Path();
        path.moveTo(canvas.getWidth()/2, diff/2);
        path.lineTo(canvas.getWidth() / 2,canvas.getHeight()-diff/2);

        if(this.isPressed() || this.isFocused()) {
            paint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.light_gray));
        } else {
            paint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.main_kosapp));
        }
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }
}
```

The problem is, that the `onDraw` method gets not called after I press the view. I tried to set `duplicateParentState` to true, but it did not help at all. FYI in my layout this view has two direct siblings - textviews - which both have its text color defined with selectors and it works for those textviews. 
What is wrong with my view implementation? What do I need to add to the class to make selectors working?

Comment: try adding `android:clickable="true"` in xml for your custom `View`.

Comment: try adding android:duplicateParentState="true" in your layout for your custom view

Answer (score 1):

you should invalidate your view for the pressed state by overriding the dispatchSetPressed

```
@Override
protected void dispatchSetPressed(boolean pressed) {
    super.dispatchSetPressed(pressed);
    invalidate();
}
```

at least that worked for me without using the motion events